# Using Syncfusion Circular Gauge static inject error is coming

Tags: syncfusion

core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CircularGaugePointerDirective -> CircularGaugeComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CircularGaugePointerDirective -> CircularGaugeComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CircularGaugeComponent!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CircularGaugePointerDirective -> CircularGaugeComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CircularGaugePointerDirective -> CircularGaugeComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CircularGaugeComponent!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21907)
    at resolveDep (core.js:22278)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed your query. We suspect that you are using an angular platform. So, we have prepared a simple circular gauge sample in an angular platform.

Sample link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/gauge2075885006

Still, we are not aware of your exact scenario which is replicate the issue. Kindly revert us with modify the above sample or provide the sample to replicate the issue which will be helpful in furthermore analysis and provide you the solution sooner.

Regards,

Baby.